# Way to pass multiple parameters to a function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, parameter-passing

I have written a python script which calls a function. This function takes 7 list as parameters inside the function, something like this:

```
def WorkDetails(link, AllcurrValFound_bse, AllyearlyHLFound_bse, 
                AlldaysHLFound_bse, AllvolumeFound_bse, 
                AllprevCloseFound_bse, AllchangePercentFound_bse, 
                AllmarketCapFound_bse):
```

where all the arguments except `link` are lists. But this makes my code looks pretty ugly. I pass these lists to this function because the function appends few values in all of these lists. How can I do it in more readable way for other users?

Comment: Does it add the same things to each list or different things?

Answer (score 21):

**test function:**

You can use multiple arguments represented by `*args` and multiple keywords represented by `**kwargs` and passing to a function:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print('arguments are:')
    for i in args:
        print(i)

    print('\nkeywords are:')
    for j in kwargs:
        print(j)
```

**Example:**

Then use any type of data as arguments and as many parameters as keywords for the function. The function will automatically detect them and separate them to arguments and keywords:

```
a1 = "Bob"      #string
a2 = [1,2,3]    #list
a3 = {'a': 222, #dictionary
      'b': 333,
      'c': 444}

test(a1, a2, a3, param1=True, param2=12, param3=None)
```

**Output:**

```
arguments are:
Bob
[1, 2, 3]
{'a': 222, 'c': 444, 'b': 333}

keywords are:
param3
param2
param1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change it to:

```
def WorkDetails(link, details):
```

Then invoke it as:

```
details = [ AllcurrValFound_bse, AllyearlyHLFound_bse, 
            AlldaysHLFound_bse, AllvolumeFound_bse, 
            AllprevCloseFound_bse, AllchangePercentFound_bse, 
            AllmarketCapFound_bse ]
workDetails(link, details)
```

And you would get the different values out of details by:

```
AllcurrValFound_bse = details[0]
AllyearlyHLFound_bse = details[1]
...
```

It would be more robust to turn `details` into a dictionary, with the variable names as keys, so take your pick between a few more lines of code vs. defensive programming =p

Answer (score 3):

You could use `*args` if you don't need to use names for your lists:

```
def WorkDetails(link, *args):
    if args[0] == ... # Same as if AllcurrValFound_bse == ...
        ...

 # Call the function:
 WorkDetails(link, AllcurrValFound_bse, AllyearlyHLFound_bse, AlldaysHLFound_bse, AllvolumeFound_bse, AllprevCloseFound_bse, AllchangePercentFound_bse, AllmarketCapFound_bs)
```

Or you could use a dictionary

```
def WorkDetails(link, dict_of_lists):
    if dict_of_lists["AllcurrValFound_bse"] == ...
        ...

# Call the function
myLists = {
    "AllcurrValFound_bse": AllcurrValFound_bse,
    "AllyearlyHLFound_bse": AllyearlyHLFound_bse,
    ...,
    ...
}
WorkDetails(link, myLists)
```

Comment: lipstick on a pig, the OP should define a new class that encapsulates the parameters

Comment: In these situations `collections.namedtuple` might turn out useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think that usage of **kwarg is better.
Look this example:

```
def MyFunc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs


MyFunc(par1=[1],par2=[2],par3=[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, passing more than 3 parameters to a function is not recommended. This is not specific to python but to software design in general. You can read more about how to reduce the number of parameters passed to a function [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/145055/173639).

Following the perspective of previous answers, but from a more general point of view I would like to add that there are several ways to make your code more readable:

- to divide your function in simpler ones which have fewer arguments (define a function that takes your variable `link`, `specific_list`, `list_type`. By doing this you can detect within your `WorkDetails` function which list you passed with `list_type` and add the correct elements to that `specific list`)
- to create a parameter object/data structure which is passed to your function (this is what previous answers suggested using [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552963/3301367), [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552957/3301367)...)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

That you need to pass that many lists is a sign that your function is not doing just one thing and you should refactor it by breaking it into smaller functions and/or converting it to a class. You can pass parameters as keywords, or pass an arbitrary number of parameters to a function, as described by [this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters), but it'll still be hard for others to read and understand if you have your function do more than one thing.